# ASP.NET Core currency format did not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

While trying to display currency with the attribute `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` and using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Variable)`, the format is not displaying correctly on my OS X computer while debugging locally. It shows up as a `¤` symbol instead of `$`.

Comment: `¤` is the [unspecified currency character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)). I would assume that you didn’t set up your server’s locale properly, so it does not know it needs to use dollars. You’re probably better of generating the currency symbol yourself anyway though, as the symbol would change depending on your locale which is likely not a good behavior for your application.

Comment: How would I go about generating the currency symbol myself without hardcoding it for each of the variables?

Comment: Well, I would probably hardcode it somehow; or put it in a central config or something. – If you want to use the standard string format from the `DataType` attribute, you could also try setting the locale explicitly at application startup, but I’m not sure if that works properly.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the culture info programatically for your server in `Startup.cs`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: In .net core 3.1; Configuration.Bind(builder);

Comment: Use IWebHostEnvironment instead of IHostingEnvironment

Comment: This fixes it for me when using docker images. I am not sure what the default culture is there because I just got jibberish (even though machine is running linux with en-GB) . very odd but this fixes it.. for now I dont care for any other cultures

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

Model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public string SalaryUS
        {
            get { return string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", Salary); }
        }
        public string SalaryPL
        {
            get { return string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-PL"), "{0:C}", Salary); }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Employee()
            {
                Salary = 1000
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Employee

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SalaryUS) <br/>
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SalaryPL)
```

Result:

```
$1,000.00 
1 000,00 zł
```

Comment: Good luck adding 60 currencires to 500 classes when needed. This is not really the best approach.. this is why Culture was made to deal with this.. and not your code . sorry but this is not good advice -1 - This is super helpful with webpages when your browser says it wants pl-PL then dotnet will set the culture to pl-PL and ToString("C") will give you zl - and if Belgian German comes along they like EUR in the front not in the end. yip.. Culture got that sorted too. use the technology that is there

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, but author of the question didn't ask for a solution to the scenario you described. This is just an "approach" and I don't see anything wrong in it if you need this in one or two places for smaller applications. I agree the accepted answer is a better one. Not all applications need to scale. Cheers :)